# Regex for URL with multuple parameters

Tags: php, regex, get

Im trying to compile a regular expression to match a URL in the following form:

```
http://www.example.com/param_1/param_2/.../param_n/?var_1=val_1&var2_=val_2&...val_n=var_n
```

In other words, the URL would have several subdirectories (param_1 - param_n) that need to be matched explicitly, and an unknown number of GET variables that need to be carried along with the URL without invalidating the match.

(Ive seen other topics for matching one, or two, or three GET variables but none for a general regex expression matching multiple variables who's total number is unknown)

I have the following Regex working for the following URL:

```
URL: http://www.example.com/users/john/

REGEX: "users\/john\/([a-z|A-Z|0-9|-]+)([\/]{0,1})\/([a-z|A-Z|0-9|-]+)([\/]{0,1})$/"  

RESULT: MATCH!! :)
```

But the addition of "GET" variables (http://www.example.com/users/john/?car=blue) does not lead to a match (obviously).

I am not a regex guru and pretty sure what I have working probably isn't very elegant to begin with, but I have had no luck at all making it work with additional variables.

I am matching patterns in the following way:

```
$routes = array(~~ REGEX => controller script ~~);
foreach($routes as $pattern=>$ctrl){
    if(preg_match($pattern, URI)) { 
        echo 'MATCH!!';
        break; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll probably need to use multiple regexes. 1) match and capture the path params and any get key-vals, 2) parse the path params and capture each one, 3) parse the get key-vals and capture each one. That's how I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

First extract all params and all key-vals separately:

```
                             key-vals vvvv
^https?:\/\/[^\/]+((?:\/[^?]+)*)?(?:\?(.+))?$
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ params
```

For the example url, params = `/param_1/param_2/.../param_n` and key-vals = `var_1=val_1&var2_=val_2&...val_n=var_n`.

If params were extracted, get each individual param (use global to get every one):

```
\/([^\/]+)
  ^^^^^^^^ individual param
```

If key-vals were extracted, get each individual key and value (also use global):

```
        vvvvvvv value
([^=]+)=([^&]+)
^^^^^^^ key
```

Sorry I can't help with the PHP, but this should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies! The following regex ended up working for me:

```
/^\/param_1\/param_2\/...\/param_n\/?(\?.*)?$/
```